# Why does Chow's theorem imply that compact complex manifolds embedded in projective space are algebraic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am trying to understand when compact complex manifolds are algebraic.  In many sources, they prove a certain complex manifold can be embedded into projective space (e.g. with the Kodaira embedding theorem) and then state that by Chow's theorem, it must be algebraic.  My question is on this last implication.

Chow's theorem states that a compact analytic subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is algebraic.  An analytic subvariety is defined as one that is locally the vanishing set of some holomorphic functions.  So, if an embedded complex manifold is indeed analytic, then Chow's theorem shows it is algebraic.

My problem is that I cannot see why this is necessarily true.  For example (if I understand correctly), in the setting of the Kodaira embedding theorem one constructs a line bundle on a Hodge manifold whose global sections give an embedding into some $\mathbb{P}^n$.  It is not at all clear to me  though why this image should be locally the vanishing set of some holomorphic functions.  Why is this?

After some searching I found a candidate answer: the "proper mapping theorem" (Griffiths-Harris, p. 395) which seems to imply this.  However, this seems to be quite a nontrivial statement and I never saw it cited along with the application of Chow's theorem, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something simpler.

Comment: Do we really need holomorphic polynomials in the definition of analytic subvariety? Can you quote some reference?

Comment: Sure: "[V] ... is an analytic variety in U if, for any p in U, there exists a neighborhood U' of p in U such that V cap U' is the common zero locus of a finite collection of holomorphic functions f_1, ... f_k on U'." Griffiths-Harris, p. 12.  I don't know how else one would define it.

Comment: So it is functions and not polynomials.....

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. (Edited)

Comment: If your concern is how the image of the embedding  (say, in the proof of Kodaira embedding theorem) is an analytic subvariety, it is easier and follows from inverse function theorem.

Comment: Normally, this just comes from the definition of a holomorphic embedding (or the holomorphic immersion theorem). Which definition of a holomorphic embedding do you use?

Comment: @ArcticChar I am not a complex geometer, but I have always understood Chow’s theorem as a special case of GAGA. An analytic subvariety of of $\mathbb{P}^{n,\mathrm{an}}_\mathbb{C}$ is cut out by a coherent ideal sheaf in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{\mathrm{an},n}_\mathbb{C}}$ which, by GAGA, must actually be the analytification of a coherent ideal sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}}$ which gives the result the OP is after. Is this not correct? (I’m asking you because, my impression, is that you’re an actual complex geometer).

Comment: I am using the definition as an injective immersion that is holomorphic as a map.  I suppose one could then use a "holomorphic constant rank theorem" to conclude, if it exists? (sounds plausible but haven't checked)  Regarding the GAGA approach, would it require Oka's theorem to show a holomorphic embedding is indeed cut out by a coherent ideal sheaf? (I am certainly even less of a complex geometer, seeing this for basically the first time.)

Comment: @Cyclicduck Yes, CRT holds in the holomorphic context as well. One usually learns this before trying harder things such as Kodaira's and Chow's theorems. The proof is the same as in the real case, by reduction to the holomorphic inverse mapping theorem.